# Issue while running "lektor server" command on Windows

Tags: python, windows, lektor

Python version: 2.7

Showing the following error on `lektor server` command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/item4/Projects/lektor/lektor/devserver.py", line 49, in build
    builder.prune()
  File "/Users/item4/Projects/lektor/lektor/builder.py", line 1062, in prune
    for aft in build_state.iter_unreferenced_artifacts(all=all):
  File "/Users/item4/Projects/lektor/lektor/builder.py", line 371, in iter_unreferenced_artifacts
    and is_primary_source''', [artifact_name])
ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer. It may helpful

I have edited /Users/item4/Projects/lektor/lektor/builder.py and added a single line

```
con.text_factory = lambda x: unicode(x, 'utf-8', 'ignore')
```

after the following line

```
con = sqlite3.connect(self.buildstate_database_filename,
                              timeout=10, check_same_thread=False)
```

Ref Link : http://hakanu.net/sql/2015/08/25/sqlite-unicode-string-problem/